# Service Fabric Statefull Service how to avoid InvalidOperationException on long running transaction with large values

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a fairly long running transaction that updates large values (dictionaries) on multiple reliable collections. I keep running into InvalidOperationExceptions (Transaction is committing or rolling back), and retrying the operation just results in the exception again. Is there anything I can do to mitigate the issue?

I assume this is related to the transaction blocking truncation of the transaction log like it says in the docs. Would making the log larger or smaller help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines

> Do handle InvalidOperationException. User transactions can be aborted by the system for variety of reasons. For example, when the Reliable State Manager is changing its role out of Primary or when a long-running transaction is blocking truncation of the transactional log. In such cases, user may receive InvalidOperationException indicating that their transaction has already been terminated. Assuming, the termination of the transaction was not requested by the user, best way to handle this exception is to dispose the transaction, check if the cancellation token has been signaled (or the role of the replica has been changed), and if not create a new transaction and retry.

Comment: without context this is difficult to answer. Consider listing the keys, then processing each key in a separate transaction? Maybe?

Comment: Yeah it works if i split up the operation into multiple transactions, but then I lose consistency if something throws an error down the line, so I really need one transaction to work. How could I get more info into what is causing the transaction to roll back? There are so many configurable settings I have a feeling increasing some limit somewhere would help, I just don't know which one.

Comment: Increasing limits would most likely just delay the same issues, if any config helps at all. If the app design relies on contentious data structures locks will always show up as a perf problem. Consider how to make the data less contentious if possible. As a generic rule (that may or may not apply here) - take the smallest lock possible that would ensure consistency.

Comment: See my posted answer. I’m fairly certain the issue was that the transaction log was truncating during the transactions because of the size of the data. Bumping up the minLogSizeInMb completely resolved the issue. I don’t believe locks were the issue as it would fail consistently with only a single thread accessing the data. My app is setup so only a single thread will ever be processing a key at a given time, serialized transaction basically.

Comment: @StenPetrov You were correct that increasing the MinLogSizeInMB only postpones the problem. Eventually there will be an operation where the transaction trunces mid transaction and I get the error again. I know the docs say to handle InvalidOperationException for this exact case and retry, but that feels dirty as all kinds of exceptions will be caught by that not just the transaction log truncating. For example if I call Single() on a collection with no items it will also throw an InvalidOperationException, and there's no need to retry that.

Comment: try making the transaction times shorter. whenever locks are needed they should be taken on the smallest surface for the shortest time possible

Comment: The transaction takes less than a second, but there's a lot of data being manipulated. Making it any shorter just isn't an option, it is wrapping what needs to be consistent. Even if it was less data in the transaction, it seems there would still be a possibility of it truncating the log during a transaction at some point. Seems to be this is a design flaw with reliable collections as a whole. It even says in the doc to handle this case.... so assuming its unavoidable.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue with reliable collections, but that was for a *very* busy service, in the order of 100 requests per second per VM. It was designed from the get-go for minimum collisions on the SF end. Chances are your service can be written in such a way as well and SF will be perfectly capable of handling it. It would, however, most likely require you to redesign the persistence layer.
If you share some code/data I may be able to help more

Comment: My service is busy in a different way. While I don’t have 100 request per second, one click of the save button can result in 200k+ records being updated, and if any errors occur all of that must succeed or rollback consistently. It takes way too long to save 200k keys, so I am storing dictionaries as my values containing all of the records on a single key. The data layer is simple, just one collection with a dictionary value per key. I can’t really share any code but I think the scenario is simple enough to speak for itself. Any recommendation?

Comment: I already have a sql backend, adding in the reliable collection as a caching store to eliminate the latency of pulling and pushing all of those records to the database. Redesigning it is easy as my use case is simple, but I haven’t found a better way to do it. Speed is of the essence as the user is awaiting a response after clicking save. It works very fast, but eventually always hits an error when the transaction log truncates due to the size of the value. The best I can come up with is setting the log size to a huge value (think 20gb) then have retry logic to handle the inevitable failure

Comment: @StenPetrov see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure exactly which setting did it, but I got it working with the following

```
        new ReliableStateManagerConfiguration(new ReliableStateManagerReplicatorSettings
        {
            CheckpointThresholdInMB = 4096,
            MaxRecordSizeInKB = 1024 * 1024,
            MinLogSizeInMB = 4096,
        })))
```

Thinking that bumbing up the MinLogSizeInMB stopped it from attempting to truncate the log during the transaction due to the large values.

Unfortunately this just allows a single transaction to complete. Eventually the log has to truncate and whichever transaction is in progress when that happens fails and has to be retried. Would be nice if there was some way around that. I'm tempted to make the MinLogSizeInMB a huge number to make these errors as few and far between as possible.